# Glass/Magnification Effect — After Effects

Tags: animation

How can I achieve this glass distortion effect that is caused by the circle in the middle? I am trying to achieve exactly the same level of distortion around the edges etc.

[Link to the original Instagram post](https://www.instagram.com/p/B4sG3wGDs3H/?utm_source=ig_web_options_share_sheet)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cc_glass for this sort of thing. There are great tutorials by andrew kramer from videocopilot, they might help you. Alternatively, this effect could also be created using a lens distort - you might want to try slapping it onto an adjustment-layer and masking the layer with a circle.